# FQL for returning all album names and object id's of the albums for ALL friends of a user

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-fql

looking for fql query to grab all albums of all friends,

extra points for complete js example using FB.Data.query and jQuery to spit out results as they come in. thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `friends_photos` permission and then use:
***Javascrip:***

```
$("#friends-albums").click(function() {
    FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 25'
        },
        function(resp) {
            $.each(resp, function(k,v) {
                console.log(v.name)
            })
        }
    );
});
```

***HTML:***

```
<button id="friends-albums">Get Albums</button>
```

Note:

- I'm using jQuery
- To get the full list, remove `LIMIT 25` from the query string
- `console.log` is a firebug command, use `alert()` instead if you don't have firebug.