# How to get total number of albums of all facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

How to get total number of albums of all facebook friends?

I want to retrieve all facebook friends total albums in one go.

Anyone have have idea how to query "album" table in FB

plz share ur thoughts thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've came across this link earlier today, sound similar to your question
[FQL for returning all album names and object id's of the albums for ALL friends of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911700/fql-for-returning-all-album-names-and-object-ids-of-the-albums-for-all-friends)

If you removed the "LIMIT 25" as [ifaour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337227/ifaour) mentioned from his example side note, the query would look like this and do the task

```
SELECT aid, owner, name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

2nd step: let's put it into a multi-query format

```
{"query1":"SELECT aid, owner, name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())","query2":"SELECT owner, album_object_id, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM #query1)"}
```

I guess you'll need to modify the fields in query2 to fit it into your scenario

These will return as 2 big fat json objects with 5000 results limit... which I haven't figured out a solution to query the next 5000 and the rest...

Also, I think there's a bug in both FQL and Graph API, some of my friends' albums are NOT showing in the result... (yes, with the right permission and necessary scopes to browse and query...) I've fired a bug report for this issue

Comment: IN clauses have a limit on # of items, so if you have more than (some random # around 75) friends, the IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friends...) will not actually contain all your friends, but rather first 75 or so ids sorted ascending

Comment: The 5000 result limit it's a big issue. I think if we want the more accurate result, we would need to break down the whole program into small parts to do the query first.

Let's say get the full friend list first, and get their album list (perhaps each query per account?)... then go through the albums and get the photos?

But... when you querying EACH of your friend's albums (or photos), you'll realized the API bug I mentioned above... some of them will return an empty object even you have got everything required.